# Multi dates in columns

Tags: sql, sorting, teradata

I work for a telco company, each month I load a list of numbers into a table, I have the code below that shows what department they spoke to and sorted by the import date.

Currently I have to add a new `count(case)` statement for each import date, is there a way I can run it so it picks up the new dates and places them in column so I don't have to go add a new count(case) statement each time new data is loaded.

```
sel 
  dept
  ,count(case when import_date = '2013-03-26' then import_date
    else null end) as "WE 26/03"
  ,count(case when import_date = '2013-07-25' then import_date
    else null end) as "WE 25/07"
  ,count(case when import_date = '2013-08-22' then import_date
    else null end) as "WE 22/08"
  ,count(case when import_date = '2013-09-09' then import_date
    else null end) as "WE 09/09"
from IPSHARE.HRData
inner join IPSHARE .RMO_CHURN_TRIGGER
  on msn = svc_no
group by dept;
```

The output looks as follow

```
dept            | WE 26/03  | WE 25/07    |WE 22/08   |WE 09/09

Mobile Retention|   57,433  | 26,185      |24,686     |23,593
Mobile Tech     |   21,036  | 11,999      |7,566      |7,429
FS Low Risk     |   17,988  | 8,074       |7,879      |7,917
General         |   17,068  | 10,111      |5,226      |4,549
Bus Mob Retent  |   16,737  | 16,477      |396        |736
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a dynamic pivot table via SQL where the column headings are labeled based on a calculated value derived from the `import_date` column?

Comment: yes, thats what im trying to do, basically the import date gets updated at irregualar times, and i want the coloums to be import_date. Doesnt have to be in the format shown (we dd/mm) but just would like the coloumns to be generated from the source

Answer (score 1):

SQL92 has the function EXTRACT

Its usage is `select EXTRACT(DAY FROM import_date)`

So I guess you could do

`select 'WE' + EXTRACT(DAY FROM import_date) + '/' + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM import_date) from IPSHARE.HRData`

Comment: I think the OP is trying to build a dynamic pivot report via SQL. While the EXTRACT function will perform as you indicated I don't think this completely addresses what the OP is trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi Rob - i am looking doing a Pivot but i can find any information on how to do pivot/transpose the data in Teradata, can you provide any assistance to me.

Comment: Normally a pivot can be done with CASE logic as you have listed in your question. Trying to do it dynamically in SQL may not be possible without doing a stored procedure to build a dynamic SQL statement.